# Esiste una parola che significhi 'il giorno dopo dopodomani'?

Tags: word-choice

Girando per il Sud dell'Italia non è infrequente sentir dire 'crè', 'piscrè' e 'piscrìgh', quali parole dialettali significanti, rispettivamente, domani, dopodomani e il giorno successivo a dopodomani.

Chiaramente, così come accade per l'inglese, in assenza di un alfabeto fonetico le tre parole che ho scritto usando le lettere dell'alfabeto italiano, pur con gli accenti, non colgono precisamente il suono delle stesse, e sono possibili variazioni da una località a l'altra.

Pur nelle possibili diversità, vi risulta che nei dialetti parlati nel Nord dell'Italia vi sia una parola che significhi 'il giorno dopo dopodomani', o addirittura una  parola che significhi 'il giorno successivo al giorno dopo dopodomani'?

Comment: Curiosità: i vari "cré" e compagnia dialettali vengono diretti dal latino "cras", ovvero "domani", eventualmente attaccandoci davanti un "pis" derivato per qualche via da "post". La parola italiana "domani", invece, recupera la locuzione di latino volgare "de mane", ovvero di mattina (prossima); in sintesi, i dialetti del meridione sono rimasti più vicini all'originale latino rispetto alla lingua "ufficiale".

Comment: Tra l'altro, pare che in Puglia ci sia una [fioritura incredibile di termini per specificare giorni prima o dopo oggi](http://freeforumzone.leonardo.it/d/751328/crai-piscrai-e-piscriddi/discussione.aspx?idm1=10868245&pl=4) :D

Comment: @MatteoItalia Bello l'appunto sull'etimo delle parole citate (che peraltro io non ho mai sentito, pur provenendo dal "Sud"), però non credo che questo basti da solo per affermare che i dialetti del Sud sono più vicini al Latino rispetto all'italiano ufficiale.

Comment: @martina: pardon, sono stato poco chiaro, non intendevo dire che siano *sempre* più vicini al latino, ma in questo specifico caso sì.

Comment: In veneto si può sentir dire “oggi otto” per indicare la una settimana dopo.

Comment: In che parte del Veneto? Io non l'ho mai sentito (entroterra veneziano/trevigiano)

Comment: Io (Roma), ho sentito dire cose come “oggi a otto” o “domani a otto”, in un senso analogo. Non era questo che si chiedeva nella domanda, però.

Comment: Anzi, è italiano standard: “*oggi a otto*, l’ottavo giorno a contare da oggi” ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/otto)).

Comment: “Oggi otto” significa “fra una settimana esatta”; siccome mentre scrivo è sabato, “oggi otto” significherebbe “sabato prossimo”. Veneto centrale, Padova.

Comment: Sicuro di “oggi otto”, @egreg? Il Treccani e altri dizionari registrano solo “oggi a otto” (che combacia con la mia esperienza, ma non vuol dire molto).

Comment: @DaG In veneto è così; naturalmente le doppie sono indicative, la pronuncia è “ogi oto”.

Comment: @egreg se dici "oggi 8" a Milano pensano che oggi tu preferisca prendere il tram (linea 8) :)

Answer (score 8):

No, there are no words meaning "in three days", besides the obvious ("fra tre giorni"), but there are really many ways to say "the day after tomorrow".

> - Dopodomani
> - Posdomani
> - Domani l'altro

Probably if you said "Dopodomani l'altro" you may be understood but it's not an idiom I've heard before.

Furthermore, [you can say (although it's rare to hear)](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/domani/)

> - Domani a otto (o domani otto), meaning "tomorrow week"
> - Domani a quindici (o domani quindici), meaning "tomorrow fortnight"

So, again, stretching Italian quite a lot, maybe you could say "Domani a tre", but I doubt this would be understood at all.

Comment: +1 per l'eccellente servizio notturno che vedo svolgi qui!

Comment: In Lombardia non ho mai sentito "domani a otto" o "a quindici", forse è diffuso solo in alcune regioni d'Italia.

Comment: I'm not sure that "dopodomani l'altro" would be understood. I personally would not.
I also never heard of "domani a otto" and "domani a quindici". Probably they are used only in some regions.

Comment: @matteo I've never of it either, but found it on the treccani site. I'll add a link...

Comment: @Skliwz here the link http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/domani/. It looks like it was an expression used by Manzoni. I don't think anyone use it now :)

Comment: Finora ho sempre creduto che "posdomani" invece stesse proprio a indicare "il giorno dopo dopodomani"!

Comment: If someone says *domani a otto* I would probably think of some kind of eight-a-side indoor football match tomorrow.

Comment: posdopodomani sarebbe probabilmente capito da tutti ed è infatti quello che io uso (suona un po' meglio di dopodopodomani) però non è affatto comune

Comment: @MatteoItalia Non mi è chiaro se stiamo parlando di dialetti nord-italiani o di italiano in questa risposta, ma ti posso dire che nel dialetto della mia zona (bassa bergamasca) si usa la traduzione letterale di "oggi otto" (*Ancö ot*) per dire "tra esattamente una settimana".

Comment: Se dici "domani a 8" a Milano, pensano che tu abbia dimenticato "alle"...

Answer (score 7):

You could get away with "dopodopodomani" ([no, really](https://www.google.com/?q=%22dopodopodomani%22#q=%22dopodopodomani%22)) in very informal speech, but it is far more common to refer to it as either "tra tre giorni" or just by the weekday ("Martedì").

Comment: Even if it's not used in formal contexts, I would understand _dopo dopodomani_ and _dopo dopodopodomani_. I would not really use _dopo dopodopodomani_ because people would start counting the days on their hands. `:)` The shorter is the weekday, since it is normally understood as the coming one.

Comment: "Dopodopodomani" is easy to understand but don't forget the rolling-finger "afterwards" gesture. :-)

Comment: @MauroVanetti As they say, Italian is a sign language with sounds for accompainment...